# transform a general linear second-order equation into the hypergeometric equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, asymptotics

Show that a general linear second-order equation with three regular singular points at 0, 1, and $\infty$ and no other singular points can be transformed into the hypergeometric equation.